Buscador para Excel (xls,xslx) con iniciales de nombre y apellido
Buen día.
Tengo un problema, una lista de clientes en Excel de más de 67.000 filas, en la que tengo números de identidad, nombres y apellidos y direcciones, lo que necesitaría y desconozco cómo; es poder buscar personas con dos iniciales de nombre y apellidos, por ejemplo: tengo a Perez Juan, y yo aporto las iniciales Ju Pe, o Pe Ju, alguno tiene idea si es posible?
Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Filtra manualmente usando caracteres comodín. Si por ejemplo, a la hora de filtrar dices que contiene el texto *pe*ju* te sacará todo lo que contenga ambas sílabas

Muchísimas gracias, era justo lo que estaba buscando!
